# require('https') vs require('tls')

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, express

I'm trying to create a very secure connection between client and server using Node.js, Express.js and TLS (1.2).

I think my problem is in understanding what TLS actually is - meaning what is being exchanged, when and how by who.

Anyhow, I'm searching the internet like a nutter (crazy person) to try and figure out following:

- what does `var tls = require('tls');` invoke?
- what does `var https = require('https');` invoke?

I can get tls working when using another node as a client, but in this case the client will be a user in a browser. Can I use both for a browser or only https??

Thanks

Comment: The `https` lib uses `tls` for its transport.  TLS for conversational purposes is just SSL.  If your user is a browser, just use HTTPS.

Comment: Joe thanks for commenting. Much clearer now - Avery's response kind of puts everything in perspective. Cheers.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Let's indeed start with what TLS is.

TLS is a way to provide secure connections between a client and a server. It does this by providing a safe way for clients and servers to exchange keys so they can then use public-key cryptography to secure their transmission.  The exact mechanism is found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Protocol_details), but it's really not important for this answer.

Now, what is https? Well first, let's talk about [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). HTTP is a protocol that defines how web servers and clients talk and exchange web pages or data.  Basically, it includes a request from a client and the server responds with a numerical message, headers, and (optionally) a body.  If you're familiar with writing web pages, this is obvious.

So now, finally, what is HTTPS? [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) is a version of HTTP using TLS to secure data. This means that clients and servers can use the same protocol they're used to, wrapped in encryption.

Now, let's talk about these in node.js.

When you use `require('tls')`, you're only using the encryption layer, without defining the protocol. This will work fine for anything that doesn't expect an exact protocol, such as your other node.js client.

When you use `require('https')`, you're specifically using HTTP over TLS. The [https module](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) <strike>is actually a subclass of the</strike> [tls module](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html)! (Oops, actually, the `https.Server` is a subclass of `tls.Server`) This means that whenever you're using the https module, you're also using the tls one.

Now, the final question: What does the browser want? If you've been following everything I've said, you can see that the browser wants https. In fact, it's likely that most of the webpages you've visited today has been over https.

Comment: Most of this I already knew, but it was the distinguishing fact of TLS being and Arbitrary encryption mechanism versus a mecheanism with a specified protocol.